# Get linked issues in JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I would like to get the linked issues for a specific issue through the JIRA REST API.

I would like to use the URL: https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9

I tried the following:

- Adding ?fields=summary,issuelinks
- Adding /remotelink to the URL
- Using the [IssueLink](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issueLink)

It should be there if I call the getIssue method [according to the documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue).

What am I doing wrong? Hope somebody can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You first have to use your own JIRA domain, like http://localhost:8080

and then just add the following JQL:
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/JRA-9?fields=issuelinks